# Android ListView setAdapter issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm trying to bind data do a listview on android, but I'm not able to.

I saw some code on the internet and it worked, but I just don't know why, and I don't want to create a new ListView on the fly, I want to use the one that is listed on the main.xml

Why I can do this:

```
ListView lv = new ListView(this);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,PEOPLE));
        setContentView(lv);
```

But I can't do this:

```
ListView listPessoas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listPessoas);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.listPessoas, PESSOAS);
        listPessoas.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your error here is when you are creating the new `ArrayAdapter`. You are passing `R.id.listPessoas` as the row view to use for each row. This is the id of the `ListView`. The [adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20T%5B%5D%29) is looking for a layout id containing a text view to be used for each row of the list. Change the `R.id.listPessoas` to `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` and your code should work. The `simple_list_item_1` layout is just a `TextView` that the data will be bound to.

Answer (score 2):

What is `R.id.pessoas`??

This works fine for me:

```
String[] x = new String[]{"AAA","BBB","CCC"};
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
ArrayAdapter<String> test = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,x);
lv.setAdapter(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have written is not correct, the second parameter in the array adapter constructor should be the simple layout for each list item not again your list view.

If your have a custom complex layout for your list item you need to write a custom adapter as well.

Answer (score -1):

If you are getting error.

getApplicationContext(); will work instead of 'this'.